# Is there such an ordinal as ω-1?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Sorry for the daft question, but is there such an ordinal 'ω-1' such that ω = ('ω-1')⁺?
Still trying to learn set theory and ordinal arithmetic is absolutely boogling me

Comment: Again, sorry if this is a ridiculously stupid question! Set theory is quite confusing, and ordinal arithmetic is the worst of the lot

Comment: There's no such ordinal. $\omega$ is not the successor of any ordinal. There is an extension of ordinal numbers, the surreal numbers, that include $\omega-1$, but let me give you two warnings about that. First, the addition of the surreal numbers is not exactly the same as ordinal addition. Second, I don't recommend reading about the surreal numbers until you get a better grasp of ordinal numbers.

Comment: Ordinals which are not the successor of any other ordinal are called "limit ordinals."

Comment: No. $\omega$ is the smallest ordinal larger than every natural number. It makes no sense to subtract one from it. The result can neither be a natural number , nor an infinite odrinal.

Comment: So, Ordinal Arithmetic might be confusing you due to notation and

Answer (score 1):

For small ordinals, it can be helpful to think about well-ordered subsets of familiar ordered sets like the real numbers. $\omega$ is order-isomorphic to $\Omega = \{ 1 - \frac{1}{n} \mid n = 1, 2 \ldots \}$. Adding $1$ to (or taking the successor of) an ordinal represented as a subset of the reals is adding a new element to the right of all the existing elements. Subtracting $1$ from (or taking the predecessor of) an ordinal represented as a subset of the reals is finding an element such that there is exactly one element to its right in the subset. Subtraction isn't always possible and $\Omega$ shows why: there are infinitely many elements of $\Omega$ to the right of any given $x \in \Omega$.